# How to fix this C++ program?

Tags: c++

I got the homework of the typical distance traveled in my c++ class. However, in this problem the teacher said that I cannot use the "for" loop, and I'm only allowed to use the "while loop", so I'm stuck with this code.

The problem is that the hours should display the distance traveled individually, but it displays the total amount of the distance traveled in each hour.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double distance,
           speed,
           time,
           counter=1;


    cout << "This program will display the total distance travel each hour.\n\n";

    cout << " What is the speed of the vehicle in mph?  ";
    cin >> speed;

    while(speed < 0)
    {
        cout << " Please enter a positive number for the speed:  ";
        cin >> speed;
    }

    cout << " How many hours has it traveled?   ";
    cin >> time;

    while(time < 1)
    {
        cout << " Please enter a number greater than 1 for the hours:  ";
        cin >> time;
    }


    cout << endl;
    cout << " Hour" << "\t\t" << " Distance Traveled" << endl;
    cout << " ------------------------------------" << endl;

    while(counter <= time)
    {
        distance = speed * time;
        cout << counter << "\t\t" << distance << endl;
        counter++;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A while loop and a for loop are basically the same thing.  Do you know how to do it with a for loop?

Comment: Yes, I did with the for loop, but as I said my teacher is asking me for the while loop.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I can't figure out what this means: "*The problem is that the hours should display the distance traveled individually, but it displays the total amount of the distance traveled in each hour.*" What is the difference between listing the hours individually and listing the amount traveled in each hour?

Comment: I don't see why the result would be different with a `for` loop. The problem is simply that you're not adding the distance in each hour to a total distance.

Comment: Please change your title to describe the specific problem you're having. Your title describes 90% of questions here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to calculate distance travelled in each hour respectively (from what I could understand from code); That's because every time you iterate in while loop for `counter <= time`, you calculate the distance for that amount of time. Say for time = 1 hr, your code calculates distance travelled in 1 hour and displays it. When time is 2 hr, it calculates distance travelled in 1 hr and 2hr (total distance isn 2 hrs) respectively.

Ex:

```
time = 2, speed = 60 kmph
```

will print

```
1 60
2 120
```

where 120 is total distance in 2 hours and not distance from 1st hour to 2nd hour.

If you need to calculate the distance travelled in each hour, your time should be constant and is 1 hr (Assuming speed remains constant over the time). In order to use that in while loop, use:

```
distance = (speed * counter) - (speed *(counter - 1))
```

Distance travelled in nth hour is total distance in n hours minus distance travelled in (n-1) hours.

Answer (score -1):

Please try if it really is as easy as distance = speed * time. It looks like you got the variables `counter` and `time` mixed up. Just use `counter` at every increment and that is the local value of `time`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double distance,
            speed,
            time,
            counter=1;


    cout << "This program will display the total distance travel each hour.\n\n";

    cout << " What is the speed of the vehicle in mph?  ";
    cin >> speed;

    while(speed < 0)
    {
        cout << " Please enter a positive number for the speed:  ";
        cin >> speed;
    }

    cout << " How many hours has it traveled?   ";
    cin >> time;

    while(time < 1)
    {
        cout << " Please enter a number greater than 1 for the hours:  ";
        cin >> time;
    }


    cout << endl;
    cout << " Hour" << "\t\t" << " Distance Traveled" << endl;
    cout << " ------------------------------------" << endl;

    while(counter <= time)
    {
        distance = speed * counter;
        cout << counter << "\t\t" << distance << endl;
        counter++;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Test

```
  This program will display the total distance travel each hour.

 What is the speed of the vehicle in mph?  50
 How many hours has it traveled?   5

 Hour        Distance Traveled
 ------------------------------------
1       50
2       100
3       150
4       200
5       250
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I'm sorry to bother you.

Comment: @HugoFederico Good luck...I hope the code works for you.